# Bash: One argument per one undefined variable

Tags: bash, variable, arguments, for

Say I create a file `~/myScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for myVar; do
    echo "Hi"
done
```

If I execute `bash myScript` with no arguments I'll get nothing but if I'll execute it with one or more arguments I'll get the output per the number of these variables <sub>(the variable seems to make the script dependent in passed arguments)</sub>:

```
bash ~/myScript.sh arg0 arg1
```

The for loop, which is based on the undefined variable `myVar`, would apply `arg0` and `arg1` to itself (sorry if this phrasing is lousy) and I'll get this output:

> Hi
>
> Hi

(one "Hi" per argument).

---

I originally assumed that one `for` loop works with one argument so if I would have `myVar_0` and `myVar_1` with `arg0` and `arg1`, then `myVar_0` will work with `arg_0` and `myVar_1` will work with `arg1` but I further tested and I was wrong --- all `for` loops worked with all arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

for myVar_0; do
    echo "Hi"
done

for myVar_1; do
    echo "Hello"
done
```

will return in `bash myScript arg0 arg1`:

> Hi
>
> hello
>
> Hi
>
> hello

Sidenote: I assume that if would want "1 argument per 1 for loop" I just need to use a Bash function for local scope.

### My question

What is the name of this "all arguments per all for loops" matching that Bash does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myVar` is not undefined if the script is called with positional parameters. From man bash:

> for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
>   [...] If the in word is omitted, the for command executes list once for each positional parameter that is set

But you do not use `$myVar`.

```
for myVar; do
    echo "$myVar"
done
```

Comment: Thx. Regarding your code example, why wouldn't you say it's undefined in the sense that it doesn't have any values? I mean, I did this echo of `$myVar` and got nothing so at least philosophically I can call it "undefined" (just sharing a way for me to look at it).

Comment: @Arcticooling It is in a certain way undefined if the script is called without positional parameters. But even in that case it is well defined what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop in Bash / POSIX shell is similar to e.g. the `for` loop in Python: the loop variable takes the listed values, one-by-one, and the loop body runs once for each value.

So this:

```
for x in foo bar; do
    echo "$x"
done
echo finally x is "$x"
```

is similar to

```
x=foo        # assign value
echo "$x"    # loop body
x=bar        # same with the second value...
echo "$x"
echo finally x is "$x"   # this isn't part of the loop body
```

except that you don't need to repeat the loop body. If we have an array variable `A`, `for x in "${A[@]}"; do...` loops over the values of the array. Similarly `for x in "$@"; do...` loops over the positional parameters, i.e. the command line arguments, since they're what `"$@"` expands to. And `for x; do` is basically just shorthand for `for x in "$@"; do`

So, this would print all the command line arguments:

```
for x; do                 # or: for x in "$@"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$x"
done
```

To access the arguments directly by index, use `$1` for the first, `$2` for the second argument, etc...

```
printf "the first arg is %s and the second is %s\n" "$1" "$2"
```